# What is the opposite of a server which is "down"?

Tags: single-word-requests, computing

When you say that "The server is down", you refer to a remote computer/program which is not responding.

1. How do you call the opposite state in which everything is working?
2. What is the correct verb to negate the "down" state of the server? for example: "Turn it back on", "Activate it" or something else which is more appropriate?

Comment: The system is up. The system is functional. We fixed it.

Comment: @TinfoilHat "fix it" sounds a bit too general. Is there something  more specific in this case?

Comment: Well, what specifically caused it to go down? Reboot perhaps?

Comment: @TinfoilHat That's more saying the specific action needed to repair the server. I'm asking about the more general term like "turn it up" (just for example. I don't know if it's correct)

Comment: For question 1): "the server is up and running"

Comment: The server's mood is greatly improved.  He's smiling now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a server is down, it is generally "brought back up" — the general form is "bring up".

I can't find a dictionary definition — it may be slang or jargon or too recent — but apart from my own experience working in computing, I did find a use online:

> The next day, the astronauts rebooted the system, and ground teams reported that the computer was brought back up to full functionality with no further concerns.
>
> — [Denise Chow](https://www.space.com/author/denise-chow) on [space.com](https://www.space.com/12291-shuttle-atlantis-onboard-computer-glitch.html), 2011